# Return from anonymous inner function

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are many related questions, none have the answer that helped me. In other words, questions are specific to a scenario and not isolated to issue. hence my question here:

I have a JavaScript function. Uses jQuery. I'm using an anonymous function in $.each() loop to find the object I want and return to the caller. Need help to figure out how to return from an inner function that is anonymous.

```
functions.findRider = function(riderId){
    $.each(app.riders, function(index, result) {
        if (result["id"] == riderId) {
            console.log("found the rider:"+JSON.stringify(result));
            return result;
        }
    });
    console.log("Did not find rider");
}
```

app.riders is an array of objects. Each object in the array have an Id.

Comment: This isn't the correct method for what you're attempting. Consider the native `Array.prototype.find` instead, i.e. `[1, 2, 3].find(function (e) {return e + 8 === 10;}); // 2`

Comment: @PaulS. Great suggestion, I'll try this. Thanks

Comment: Paul's suggestion is the right answer.  Filter is a close second.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to create a variable outside the `$.each()` function and add to it from inside the loop:

```
functions.findRider = function(riderId){
    var results = [];
    $.each(app.riders, function(index, result) {
        if (result["id"] == riderId) {
            console.log("found the rider:"+JSON.stringify(result));
            results.push(result);
        }
    });
    console.log("Did not find rider");
}
```

As far as I know (but I might be mistaken), there is no way to return from an anonymous function like this.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan, helps clarifying two things, 1, return is not possible, 2. work around.

Comment: @Aragorn If this helps you, please accept. If not, feedback please?

Comment: This definitely helped to understand the workaround, but I'd accept PaulS' suggestion. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.filter` for this kinda search

like this

```
functions.findRider = function(riderId) {
    var data = app.riders.filter(function(x) {
        return x.id == riderId;
    });
    return data.length > 0 ? data[0] : null;
}
```

Comment: Good point, but this doesn't really answer the question of returning from an anonymous function

Comment: I like the suggestion here, trying it out.